# An element of a subgroup's coset with one of its elements is itself ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

G is a group with a normal subgroup H. The coset

xH = H <=> x€H

How do I prove that ?

Answer (score 1):

Going through definitions, $g_1H=g_2H \iff g_1g_2^{-1}\in H$

This is a direct consequence of the equivalence relation $a \equiv b  \iff ab^{-1}\in H$. (Left) Cosets are the equivalence classes of this relation.

Answer (score 1):

$\implies$: Multiply $x$ with the unit element of $G$.

$\impliedby$: Use that $H$ is closed under the operation.

Answer (score 1):

The result holds for every subgroup, not just normal ones.

Also, recall the definition: $xH = \{ xh : h \in H \}$.

> $xH = H \implies x \in H$

If $xH = H$, then $x = xe \in xH = H$, and so $x \in H$.

> $ x \in H \implies xH = H$

If $x \in H$ and $h \in H$, then $xh \in H$,  and so $xH \subseteq H$. 
Moreover, $h = x (x^{-1}h) \in xH$, and so $H \subseteq xH$.

Comment: Not saying that this is wrong, but this answer completely ignores the fact that the OP has not understood the definition of cosets in the first place. It just gives him the fish, but doesn't teach him how to fish. :)